# How add clip art at run time on button click

Tags: javascript

Hello 
I am working on project where I need to customize our card at run time.
Mean when user click on a button then it will show a horizontal slider(that contain images ) user click one of the image and images comes over the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set the element that you want to display to `display:none` and then add an `onClick` event to the button that sets the same display property to `display:inline`

```
<div style="display:none;"></div>
<div style="display:inline;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but actually i want gallary like where user can add image.Mean when user click on add clip button a it show horizontal slider or somthing like popup window where  from user can select image as user select that image it will show on page.